# Accessing object variable in extended generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

For an assignment, I have to create and manipulate a generic object arraylist `MyArrayList<E>` extended from `java.util.ArrayList<E>`. I need to access a variable `highScore` inside the object `GameEntry` for the purpose of adding the entry into a `MyArrayList` if it meets the requirements, but I can't seem to do it?

**GameEntry class**

```
public class GameEntry
{   public String name;
    public int highScore;
    public String handle;

    public GameEntry()
    {   name = this.name;
        highScore = this.highScore;
        handle = this.handle;
    }

    public GameEntry(String n, int hs, String h)
    {   name = n;
        highScore = hs;
        handle = h;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getHScore() { return highScore; }
    public String getHandle() { return handle; }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + handle + ", " + name + ": " + highScore + ")";
    }
}
```

**MyArrayList class**

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends java.util.ArrayList<E>
{   private int numEntries = 0;
    public MyArrayList() { super(); }
    public MyArrayList(int capacity) { super(capacity); }

    public boolean isListEmpty() { return this.isEmpty(); }

    // add new score to MyArrayList (if it is high enough)
    public void addInOrder(GameEntry e) {
        int newScore = e.getHScore();

        // is the new entry e really a high score?
        if(numEntries<this.size() || newScore > this.get(numEntries-1).getHScore())
        //ERROR: cannot find symbol - method getHScore()
        // ...rest of addInOrder code...
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because `this.get(numEntries - 1)` will return a generic, and the program will not be able to use `getHScore()` with it unless you cast it to `GameEntry`.

You can do this by checking to see if it *is* a `GameEntry` object with `instanceof` and then casting it:

```
public void addInOrder(GameEntry e) {
    int newScore = e.getHScore();

    // is the new entry e really a high score?
    if (this.get(numEntries - 1) instanceof GameEntry) {

        GameEntry ge = (GameEntry) this.get(numEntries - 1); //Cast to GameEntry
        if(numEntries<this.size() || newScore > ge.getHScore()) {
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
   //Add behavior for when it is NOT an instance of GameEntry
}
```

There are probably better ways to implement the behavior you want for `addInOrder`, but I thought I'd answer your literal question on why `getHScore()` is not working for you correctly.